# JAVA loop through children of Nodelist

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML file call it (FromThis.xml) with sample data see below:

I want to read from the file(FromThis.xml) , store the values in variable then use those variable while creating a second XML file(ToThis.xml).

Brief description of my scenario[ I will read values from XML file(FromThis.xml) first and store them in a variables. Then I will use the variables to update the second xml file which is (ToThis.xml .I later use this xml to create some JSON file in some specified format.) I have been working with this but later we need to send array of elements in (FromThis.xml). From my code below i can only get the first array element but i want to loop through the elements, store them and use it to create the second xml (ToThis.xml)

(FromThis.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Root>
    <ankomstDato>2020-08-20</ankomstDato>
    <planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe>
        <element>
                <antall>67</antall>
                <kode>SLAKTEGRIS</kode>
        </element>
        <element>
                <antall>4</antall>
                <kode>UNGSAU</kode>
        </element>

    </planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe>
</Root>
```

(ToThis.xml) Below xml is what i currently get.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <string key="ankomstDato">2020-08-20</string>
    <array key="planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe">
       <map>
          <number key="antall">67</number>
          <string key="kode">SLAKTEGRIS</string>
       </map> 
    </array>   
 </map>
```

What i would like to get as the result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <string key="ankomstDato">2020-08-20</string>
    <array key="planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe">
       <map>
          <number key="antall">67</number>
          <string key="kode">SLAKTEGRIS</string>
       </map> 
       <map>
        <number key="antall">4</number>
        <string key="kode">UNGSAU</string>
     </map>
    </array>   
 </map>
```

Below is my Code

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
    import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
    import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
    import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
    import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
    import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
    import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
    
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;
    //** */
    
    public class SolutionXML2XmlFormat {
        //Create Public Variables to store data
        //**
        public static String ankomstDato_value; //1
        public static String[] planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe_antall_value = new String[6]; //
        public static String[] planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe_kode_value = new String[6]; //
    
        //+++
    
        public void Xml2JavaObject(String FromThis){
            //read the xml(TheXMLPath) and store values in variables
            // Boolean and numbers should be having values for string use " " if empty
            
    
            try {
    
                File file = new File(FromThis);
                DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                        .newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document document = documentBuilder.parse(file);
                document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                System.out.println("Root element :" + document.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
                System.out.println("------------------------ \n");
                
                //1 . ankomstDato
                String ankomstDato = document.getElementsByTagName("ankomstDato").item(0).getTextContent();
                ankomstDato_value = ankomstDato;
                //end ankomstDato
    
                  NodeList planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe= document.getElementsByTagName("planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe");
                  for (int temp = 0; temp < planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe.getLength(); temp++) {                
                      Node nNode = planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe.item(temp);
                      System.out.println("\n Current Elements :" + planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe.getLength());
                      System.out.println("\n No. of  Element :" + temp);
      
                      if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                          Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                          String element18 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("antall").item(0).getTextContent();                    
                          planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe_antall_value[temp] = element18;  
      
                          String element19 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("kode").item(0).getTextContent();                    
                          planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe_kode_value[temp] = element19;               
                          
                                          
                      } 
                  } 
    
                    
     
                
             } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
                          
            //Call method to write values
            Write2XMLfile();
        }
        
        
        public void Write2XMLfile(){
    
            XPathFactory xpathFact = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpathFact.newXPath();
    
        try {
    
            //
            String filepath = "E:/utils/Tothis.xml";
            //
    
            
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);
    
            // 1. ankomstDato
            Node ankomstDato = (Node) xpath.evaluate("(/map/string[@key='ankomstDato'])[1]", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
            ankomstDato.setTextContent(ankomstDato_value );
            // End ankomstDato
    
            //2.  planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe **************************
            System.out.println("\n This is second" );
            Node planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe = (Node) xpath.evaluate("/map/array[@key='planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe']/*", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
            if(null != planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe) {
                NodeList nodeList = planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe.getChildNodes();
                for (int i = 0;null!=nodeList && i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node nod = nodeList.item(i);
                    //System.out.println("\n");
                    if(nod.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                        NodeList arrayElements_18 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/map/array[@key='planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe']/*", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                        //System.out.println("\n number of elements" + arrayElements_18.getLength());
                        for (int j = 0; j < arrayElements_18.getLength(); j++) {
                            //.  antall
                            Node antall = (Node) xpath.evaluate("(/map/array/map/number[@key='antall'])[1]", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
                            antall.setTextContent(planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe_antall_value[j]);
                            // end antall
    
                            //.  kode
                            Node kode = (Node) xpath.evaluate("(/map/array/map/string[@key='kode'])[1]", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
                            kode.setTextContent(planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe_kode_value[j]);
                            //System.out.println("\n\n antall: " + planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe_antall_value[j]);
    
                            // end kode                       
                        }                    
                    }
                         
                }
            }
    
            // end array planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe
            
    
            // write the content into xml file
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
            transformer.transform(source, result);
    
            System.out.println("Done Updating The Api_XML_Format.xml");
    
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
            tfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException sae) {
       

     sae.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XPathExpressionException xee) {
        xee.printStackTrace();
    }

    
     }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per the given code, `planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe` NodeList size is a one. because you select the `<planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe>` element.

```
NodeList planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe = document.getElementsByTagName("planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe");
```

hence, in the for loop, declared arrays collect the first `<element>` values only from FromThis.xml file.

```
<element>
    <antall>67</antall>
    <kode>SLAKTEGRIS</kode>
</element>
```

**Solution**

get the `<element>` NodeList into `planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe` as follows,

```
NodeList planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe = document.getElementsByTagName("element");
```

Comment: thank you, replacing "planlagtAntallPerUndergruppe" with "element" solved the the first part of extracting data from xml file "FromThis.xml". The challenge am facing is assigning those values to method "Write2XMLFile" .

Comment: I have modifed method "Write2XMLFile" and posted my solution in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63842584/java-xml-how-to-use-xpath-to-find-and-add-replace-more-children-to-a-nodelist/63846828#63846828